# Building Bulk SMS Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

We are creating a bulk SMS messages sending Web application using ASP.NET web Forms and C#. 
There could be multiple logged-in users, sending bulk (1-5000) messages to their clients.

As per initial R&D we have selected to use Twilio's SMS API for this purpose. 
**But I am anxious about potential timeout issue while sending messages and saving response in loop, Also does Twilio accept multiple request instances?**

Twilio has a limit or 1 message per second Then we can only send 3600 messages in one Hour, that would be a limitation.

Twilio provide Rest API but we are not familiar with MVC, so REST API idea has been dropped.

Please suggest  other alternative, best practice and strategy to accomplish the task.

------------------**UPDATE**------------------------

**Short Code Rest API Documentation**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/short-codes

**Twilio Sending Documentation**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

**Request Data From Twilio Documentation**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With those volumes, there is no way you are going to be able to get by without using an SMS shortcode. Even if you could technically get it to work with a regular number, I suspect you would be shutdown as a spammer pumping out so many messages on a regular phone number.

A short code will let you send at at least 30 messages per second (1800/minute), and supposedly they can up that for you if you have a justified need.

https://www.twilio.com/sms/shortcodes

and this: 
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-sms-messages-be-blacklisted-as-spam

> **Can my Twilio SMS messages be blacklisted as spam?**
>
> Recipient carriers always reserve the right to filter out messages
>   from certain numbers, and routinely do so to protect their users from
>   spam.
>
> If you’ll be sending SMS messages as part of a bulk campaign (with 30
>   or more identical or similar messages going out within a few minutes),
>   we discourage you from using regular 10-digit numbers. Instead, we
>   highly recommend using an SMS short code.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly shortcodes what we need. Also should I add a 10 sec delay in loop while sending shortcodes?

Comment: With or without a shortcode, you can submit sms to the twilio queue as fast as you want, the difference will be in how fast they go out.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I have another query how to get instant sent messages response. Do we have get it later by request twilio API against sent sms ID or it should be acquired during (after) sending messages in loop.